# Phonegap: Cannot multiple SQL request in same page

Tags: jquery, sql, database, cordova

In my page I have different buttons and when each clicked it will generate different queries to access database. I already had one function "queryDB" to retrive all the data in the table and when I click the reset button, another query to UPDATE the table values.

I notice it **DID NOT** went into the FUNCTION "**resetDB**". Is it because phoneGap use "queryDB" function only? How should I solve this?

******New found problem*******
I realise when I use location.reload() it will not update the table. So I didnt use it, it did go into the function and update the database but it did not show the  "new"page. If I use href back to the settings page, it will not update the database like before.

```
$('button#reset').on("click",function(){
            var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "ApplicationDB", 200000);
            db.transaction(resetDB, errorCB);
            location.reload();
        });
```

Function resetDB

```
function resetDB(tx) {
            tx.executeSql("UPDATE RESULT SET Difficulty = 'Easy' "  , [], querySuccess, errorCB);

        }
```

Function queryDB

```
function queryDB(tx) {

        tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM RESULT ORDER BY Level"  , [], querySuccess, errorCB);
    }
```

Comment: You should elaborate your code. There's no way to tell why resetDB isn't executed. Maybe it's executed but UPDATE clause dispatches an error itself.

But this is more Web SQL / SQLite issue than PhoneGap / Cordova issue.

Comment: I put alert("resetDB") inside the function resetDB but it never executes the alert.

Comment: It does work! So like @zvona said you should provide more context. Here is an [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/T9yAD/1/) with some extra logging. (check your console for the output)

Comment: It worked when I does not reload or href the same page after update the database. This is not what I want. However I need to reload the same page again to display the updated info from database. If I href to the same page, the database will not be update, same goes with location.reload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to reload the same page again to display the updated info from
>   database.

I believe this should work for you.

```
$('button#reset').on("click",function(){              
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "ApplicationDB", 200000);
    db.transaction(resetDB, errorCB, successCB);              

});  


// Success callback
function successCB() {
    location.reload();    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JQueryMobile and want to navigate to same page, you do it like this:

$.mobile.changePage(hashedPage, {allowSamePageTransition:true});

Could you please also put more code to understand the location object?